# How/Why did Wonder Woman gain the ability to fly?

Tags: dc, wonder-woman

From what I remember, Wonder Woman couldn't fly, but now that I think about it, I watch Justice League the animated series and she does have the amazing ability of flight.

A little research showed that Hermes granted her flight, but I couldn't find the circumstances or why she was given flight later (or when for that matter).

Comment: I always just figured her invisible jet was too ridiculous for the current times, and posed way too many questions.

Comment: Flying *people*, of course, pose few questions by comparison. ;)

Comment: I miss the invisible jet :(  . I grew up watching the really cheezy justice league on cartoon network.

Comment: From the movie, I assumed she learned to fly when she realized she could (or forgot she couldn't). Like I do in dreams. Like Douglas Adams instructed in H2G2.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In the Golden Age (from the early forties to the late fifties/early sixties), the character couldn't fly at all.

In the Silver Age (late fifties/early sixties to the early eighties), Diana gained the ability to glide on air currents starting in Wonder Woman (vol 1) issue #98, May 1958.

Post-Crisis on Infinite Earths (in 1985), Wonder Woman's origin has been rebooted, and she could fly freely from the start.  Hippolyta made a baby out of clay and the goddesses (plus Hermes, for some reason) granted Diana beauty, power, strength, speed and flight.

In 2011, DC Comics' entire line of publications was relaunched, and Wonder Woman's origins have been rebooted again. This time she was a demigoddess, daughter of Hippolyta and Zeus, and was also gifted the ability to fly by Hermes. In this case Hermes scratched her with one of his feathers as Wonder Woman was trying to save Zola who was falling to her death.

Comment: What does Post-Crisis mean?

Comment: In 1985, the Crisis on Infinite Earths series caused a reboot on the chronology (more or less like the one that DC made this month). Some origins and first adventures were revamped. Wonder Woman was one of these. Her post-Crisis origin was shown in Gods and Mortals, by George Pérez: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gods_and_Mortals

Comment: She first demonstrated the power to "glide on air currents"  in the Silver Age, specifically in Wonder Woman (vol 1) issue #98, May 1958, generally regarded as the first appearance of the Silver Age Wonder Woman. In the Golden Age, she was never seen exhibiting such a power, but in later appearances the "Earth-2" Wonder Woman, meant to be the original Golden Age character, did have it. 
Every time her origin was rebooted since then (which mainly means "Crisis on Infinite Earths" and now the "New 52") she's had basically the same flight power as Superman.

Comment: @MarkReed thanks for the clarification! I will edit this information into my answer

Answer (score 5):

Wonder Woman first gained a Flight-like power as early as Issue # 98 of her original comicbook series. They referred to it as the "Power to Glide on the Air Currents". This ability became a regular part of her power set throughout the 60s, 70s and 80s.  When the Lynda Carter Wonder Woman TV Series began in 1975, the producers decided to base their rendition on the original golden age WW comics where WW did NOT have the ability to fly on her own.

When the WW Comicbook was rebooted and renumbered and had a new issue # 1 in 1986, The Greek God Hermes was shown giving Diana the Power of flight when she first came to life. In 2012, the 4th volume of her comicbook series, during a scene where Diana's friend Zola was thrown off the cliff of Mt. Olympus, the God Hermes threw one of his magic feathers  like a dart at Diana's leg and immediately after gave Diana the Power of Flight which allowed her to catch Zola.

In her current series (Volume 5), Wonder Woman was given her special powers by the Amazons' patron Gods AFTER she arrived in Man's World. Among those powers was the power of flight which Diana discovered she had during a battle with "The Sear Group" (Disciples of Ares, God of War)

Comment: Possibly the TV choice was financial - flying people would be an expensive special effect in the 70s.

Answer (score -3):

2 possibilities:

1. She was born on Themyscara and basically a demigod and she was trained by women soldiers making her able to fly because of her birthplace and heritage
2. Themyscara's gravity is stronger than Earth's and when she's on earth she can fly because of Earth's gravitational orbit making her stronger and better and maybe, possibly able to fly, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Her heritage is responsible for her flying ability, but not due to *where* she was born.  Neither can any amount of training give one the ability to fly.  Additionally, Themyscara is an island on Earth, hidden by magic.