# Did Wonder Woman Lose Her Jet When She Started Flying On Her Own?

Tags: dc, wonder-woman

I saw a number of episodes of *Justice League* while it was still showing on the Boomerang network in the U.S. and noticed some changes in the superheros in the show from what I saw as a kid.  One of them is that Wonder Woman can fly.  I understand, from [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5404/how-why-did-wonder-woman-gain-the-ability-to-fly) that this happened after *Crisis on Infinite Earths*.

I don't remember seeing any indication of Wonder Woman using her invisible plane in that series.  When Wonder Woman was given the ability to fly on her own, was the invisible plane removed from the setting as no longer needed?

Comment: She can't afford the cost of jet fuel anymore so she leaves it parked in the hanger.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, she still uses it. From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invisible_plane:

> In the current Post-Crisis version of the DC Universe, Wonder Woman can fly, regardless of wind currents, and so has little need for the Invisible Plane. The Plane's history has subsequently been revised as well.
>
> The origin of the Modern Age version of the Invisible Jet was chronicled during John Byrne's run of Wonder Woman with more detailed information chronicled in Wonder Woman Secret Files #1.
>
> The being that would one day be called the Invisible Plane began life as an alien "morphing crystal" circling a distant planet with its "family," other morphing crystals who are collectivily called the Ring. In their natural state, the Plane and its fellow members of the Ring resemble eggs made of semi transparent plastic. In time, it was separated from its family and was found by the Lansinarians, a blind subterannean race that lived underneath Antarctica. The Lansinarians could not react quickly enough to changes in their environment. Thus, they developed the morphing crystal they had found into a life support device that catered to their needs. These beings later bestow the device on Wonder Woman in gratitude for saving them. The plane, which possesses a sophisticated artificial intelligence, responds to Wonder Woman's thoughts. It is able to render itself invisible as well as alter its shape, transforming into any form of vehicle its bearer desires, be it a jet, submarine, motorcycle, or horse-drawn chariot.
>
> Wonder Woman, however, was initially unaware that her Invisible Plane was not only alive but was quite aware that it was being treated by its mistress as a lifeless tool.
>
> ...
>
> In Wonder Woman #201 (by Greg Rucka), Dome sacrifices itself to prevent a tidal wave from killing thousands of innocent people. Having "died" to save so many, Dome is now the equivalent of a human corpse. While it can still function in its traditional shape of an invisible plane, it can no longer alter its shape and is now a lifeless inanimate object that is neither intelligent nor self-aware.

Answer (score 3):

As far as animated Justice League stories, the direct to video Justice League: Crisis on Two Earths has Wonder Woman acquiring Owlman's jet plane, which has a cloaking device. At the end of the movie Wonder Woman decides to keep the invisible jet as a spoil of war.

Crisis on Two Earths was originally written to bridge The Justice League of America, and the Justice League Unlimited. Ultimately it was dropped and the story was changed slightly when it was produced after the JLU finished its run.

Comment: But she does *have* it in JLU and actually ***uses*** it to fly to the *Fortress of Solitude* in the animated adaptation of "For the Man that has Everything" (http://dcau.wikia.com/wiki/For_the_Man_Who_Has_Everything).